# Disable function using constraints

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'm trying to seperate some logic without any runtime conditions. I want to do something like code below, but it not compile with error "error: definition with same mangled name" on some_func

```cpp
    struct Utils {
        static constexpr auto is_client() noexcept -> bool {
    #ifdef DEDICATED_SERVER
            return false;
    #else
            return true;
    #endif
        }
        
        static constexpr auto is_server() noexcept -> bool {
            return !is_client();
        }
    };

    void some_func() requires (Utils::is_client()) {
       
    }

    void some_func() requires (Utils::is_server()) {
       
    }
```

I can also use 'if constexpr', but it is not convenient, and takes more code if the method should be only at the client or server.

```cpp
    void some_func() {
       if constexpr (Utils::is_client()) {
    
       } else {
    
       }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on why the `if constexpr` style of solution is bad in your case?

Comment: @Elliott It is less readable and there is an extra level of indentation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I guess it's personal preference. For me the `constexpr` nicely shows that the `if` statement will be removed before runtime. It seems more explicit and readable to me, but each to their own.